# Failed to retrieve directory listing FTPS on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftps

I have setup a FTPS server on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance using vsftpd. Im unable to connect using FileZilla.

```
Status:         Connecting to 52.32.88.85:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Status:         Connected
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (52,32,88,85,78,137).
Command:    LIST
Response:   425 Failed to establish connection.
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

From what I'm reading, FTP needs at least the listening port forwarded at the server side. How do I do this?  I tried [this](https://www.gosquared.com/blog/fix-ftp-passive-mode-problems-on-amazon-ec2-instances), but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share the vsftpd conf?

Comment: `ec2-authorize default` as shown in that example is most likely wrong.  You need to open that port range in the *correct* security group.

Comment: Is this a VPC or EC2-Classic instance?

Comment: @RodrigoM , it is a VPC instance. (Supported Platforms says VPC - VPC Default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a scan of that server and only see ports 21-22 open. For your FTPS server to work, you need to open the passive port range specified in your vsftpd.conf in your Inbound rules for your Security Group.

An example is below. NOTE: Check your actual port settings in your conf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I initiated a new instance and followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and added the following lines to my vsftpd.conf

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=12100
pasv_min_port=12000
port_enable=YES
```

I opened the port range 12000-12100 in the security group.